# IIS in Docker on Kubernetes: in-flight requests

Tags: windows, docker, iis, kubernetes

Currently, I'm running an application using VMs behind a load balancer. When I need to roll out a new version, a new set of VMs are spun up and the version gets deployed to them. The old VMs are given time to complete in-flight requests - 10 minutes in my case.

I'd like to move the whole project to Docker and Kubernetes using [Microsoft's standard images for aspnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet) but I cannot find how in-flight requests are handled with this stack.

Comment: How in-flight request ? what do you mean the way it works or the count of requests ??

Comment: [Does a Kubernetes rolling-update gracefully remove pods from a service load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611319/does-a-kubernetes-rolling-update-gracefully-remove-pods-from-a-service-load-bala) addresses at least some of this: in Kubernetes, during an upgrade, the container is sent SIGTERM and stops being sent new requests, and you can configure how long it has to shut itself down before it gets forcibly killed.